Counting number of paths for modified 1D random walk with absorbing and reflective barriers
Suppose you have a random walk starting from the origin at position $0$ with steps sampled uniformly from $\{-1, 1\}$ for all positions except when the particle reaches the reflective barrier at position $d$ ($d>0$), where the steps are sampled uniformly from $\{-1,0\}$. There is also an absorbing barrier at position $-d$, where once the particle reaches it, the walk discontinues. Is there a combinatorics approach to count the number of valid paths with length $n$?
